# Sorting a list by the values found in another list C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

Let's say I have the following two lists..

```
var unscoredList = new List<string> { "John", "Robert", "Rebecca" };

var scoredList = new List<WordScore>
{
    new WordScore("John", 10),
    new WordScore("Robert", 40),
    new WordScore("Rebecca", 30)
};
```

Is there a way I can sort the values in `unscoredList` by the values in `scoredList` where the word with the highest score appears first in `unscoredList`?

Below is the WordScore class if required..

```
public class WordScore {
    public string Word;
    public int Score;

    public WordScore(string word, int score) {
        Word = word;
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need an in-place sort, you can do this:

```
var scoreLookup = scoredList.ToDictionary(l => l.Word, l => l.Score);

var result = unscoredList.OrderByDescending(l => scoreLookup[l]);
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
unscoredList.Sort((l,r) => scoreLookup[r].CompareTo(scoreLookup[l]));
```

And of course, there should be some sanity checks done (duplicate values in scoredList, values in unscoredList which are not in scoredList, etc).

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus No worries mate

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus, beware the accepted solution will have an issue, if your data is not Dictionary compatible i.e. No data duplication in `scoredList`

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = unscoredList.OrderByDescending(x => scoredList
                       .Where(y => y.Word == x.ToString())
                       .Select(z => z.Word)
                       .FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

[image]

This returns another list, but not a big deal.

Comment: Time Complexity of O(N^2), as it traverse the inner list for every element search and then take the First. Above solution is just O(N)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks, I'm not on his level yet. I will study his approach. Will just leave this answer here for comparison with the correct one :)

Comment: Accepted solution is able to arrange the relevant data in the dictionary,so the look up time is just O(1), all that program does is go through `Unscored list` once

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yes and I also accepted that answer, I just haven't an idea that I can solve the problem on that way

Comment: @MrinalKamboj i like your areas of interest, how did you start? I want to be on that level

Comment: No level buddy, this is basic data structures and time complexity, go through any genuine book, you will able to learn and apply :). These concepts create a difference on enterprise level, when data increase, then  O(N^2) can be much higher than O(N), thus performance impact

Comment: @MrinalKamboj will take note on that! :D